# How to load a file entity by uuid?

Tags: 8, entities

So I am trying to use the default image for users in a menu block if a custom one does not exist. And for it I am getting the image file uuid:

```
$default_image = $user->get('user_picture')->getSetting('default_image');
```

Then loading the file entity:

```
$file = Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
```

This is returning null. What am I doing wrong? And is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you need?

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

if (FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', $imageFieldName)
  ->getSetting('default_image')['uuid']) {

  $imageStyle = ImageStyle::load('thumbnail');

  // Load the default image settings.
  $imageGetSettings = FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', $imageFieldName)
    ->getSetting('default_image');

  // Get the default image URI from settings.
  $imageURI = Drupal::service('entity.repository')
    ->loadEntityByUuid('file', $imageGetSettings['uuid'])
    ->getFileUri();

  // Build image style path.
  $imageStyleURL = $imageStyle->buildUrl($imageURI);

  // Set $imageURL.
  $imageURL = file_url_transform_relative($imageStyleURL);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the uuid but the $imagURI bit is returning a null. Core version is 8.9.14 and I am attempting this in hook_link_alter.

Comment: I tested with `HOOK_link_alter()` in a custom module and do see the`$imageURL` of the default image set on a user image field, e.g. `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`. Can you confirm if you see the `URI` with `kint($imageURI)`?

Comment: It turned out to be something else. For some reason even though the code returned a uuid there wasn't a file  shown as default in the interface. I uploaded a new file and it got working.